# Something about UItableviewcell height

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

1. first case,if all of the cell have equal height , with the different screen on iphone 5s ,iphone 6 and 6plus ,what should i return in the method heightForRowAtIndexPath ?
2. Then.

   ```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;  
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
   ```

what should i do before i use the code above,i just try it in a tableview on iOS 8.0 with autolayout, but it does not work.

Comment: You should provide screenshot for case 2 to show your problem.

Comment: did you correctly setup the cells' constraints?

Comment: `heightForRowAtIndexPath` also return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, if its not working, you are not properly bind the sub views to upper bound and lower bound of the cell

Comment: i did the second. How about the first case

Comment: you miss bottom constraint in cell. Please let me know hierarchy of cell (what component use in cell ). You apply bottom constraint on last `UI Component` . then It will work

Comment: Make sure you set Tableview Delegate already.

Comment: For your first Question what you need in all devices cell size will be equal base on screen height am i right ? or something else ?